# Exclude items that aren't in my collection from a js array

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection containing 10000 documents like this:

```
{"_id": 1, "name": "aaa"}
{"_id": 1, "name": "bbb"}
{"_id": 2, "name": "ccc"}
...
```

Now the front end user submits an array containing 100 names, like this:

```
myArray = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", ... "name100"]
```

And he wants to know which of the 100 are not already in the db, so I need to return a new array containing these 100 names minus those that can be found in my collection. How can I do that?

I'm using the official MongoDB driver in Node (npm mongodb).

What I currently do is first find what names ARE in the db by doing db.collection.find({name: {$in: myArray}}), and then exclude the results by javascript. But I imagine there's a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this... But I am not sure whether it works for 10000 documents or not

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      names: {
        $push: "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      newArray: {
        $setDifference: [
          [
            "name1",
            "name2",
            "name3",
            "name4"
          ],
          "$names"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [code snippet](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M2fDC0PtI7Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the all names from the collection which does not belong to the array of elements specified by user using mongodb's [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator:

```
var newArray = []    

 db.collection.find({
    name: {
        $nin: myArray
    }
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    newArray.push(doc.name)
})
```

Comment: No, what OP wanted was to filter myArray, not filter the collection

Comment: the updated answer will return the array of names that are not already present as names.

Comment: yes, based on this line from the question: 'And he wants to find out which names are not already in the db, so I need to return a new array containing all the names that are not found in my collection'